# Not able to reach base case in fibonacci sequence

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I'm quite new to Prolog, and this way of thinking is kind of messing with my mind. I'm currently using SWI-Prolog to run and debug my code. I have implemented a tail recursive algorithm to solve the N'th fibonnaci-number. I have tried debugging step by step, and I cannot explain why my implementation is skipping the base case. Where am I thinking wrong?

```
fib(0, A,_, A). %Base case, when we reach N = 0, return.
%Tail recursion. Use N as counter, iterate until base value (N=0) is  reached.
fib(N, A, B, F) :-
   Nnew is N - 1,
   Sum is (A + B),
   fib(Nnew, B, Sum, F).

fib(N, F) :-
   fib(N, 0, 1, F). %set start values for when fib(N,F). is called
```

My implementation is working great (and fast) if I want to calculate the nth fib number. For example, if I run `?- fib(5,F).`, I get F = 5 back. Great. If I want to check `?- fib(5,5).` I get `True` back, which is correct. Great.

But, if I input a false statement, for example: `?- fib(5,4).` then the program is looping forever. What happens is that N passes 0, ignores the base case(?), and continues on to be decremented. Why is the base case skipped? In my eyes, `fib(0,A,_,A).` is satisfied. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Remove the condition `N>=0` in the second clause of the predicate fib/3, the case `N=0` is included in the first clause. Should be  `N>0`.

Comment: @Yasel Sorry I missed that, was one of my attempts to fix it (which I forgot to undo). Edited now. Any clues? (N > 0) does not solve the problem.

Comment: Don't remove the condition, just changed it to `N>0`. That will avoid the infinite loop, searching over N < 0

Comment: @Yasel Oh wow, it worked. Thought I had tested that before. Would you have the possibility explaining why the base case is skipped otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the condition `N>0` to the second clause of your predicate `fib/3`, otherwise the predicate `fib/3` will continue trying with the negative numbers if the base-case fails. Lets see the case when you consult `?- fib(0,1)`:

This case will unified the second clause `fib(0,0,1,1)`, where  `Nnew` will be instantiated to the value `-1`. From here `Nnew` will be infinitely decremented, and the base-case will never be unified.

Any other `false` case, like `?- fib(5,4)` will try to decrement `N` until the base case is unified, and that won't happen unless after 5 iteration, the sum of the fibonacci numbers are equal to 4. So, there's is no point on try with more attempts.